# adding attribute in input field of Jade with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, pug

I want to add attribute in input field with a local javascript variable as:

```
-var requiredField = ('agent' == user.account_type.toLowerCase()) ? 'required' : '';

input(type='text', name="name", placeholder="Name", "#{requiredField}")
```

But I get the attribute as #{requiredField} in the html. How can this be achieved?

I am using jade.
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jade is smart enough to render the `required` attribute based off of a boolean value: `required=true` or `required=false`.

```jade
   input(type='text',required=true)
   input(type='text',required=false)
```

will render out as:

```html
<input type='text' required />
<input type='text' />
```

So for your code sample, try this instead:

```jade
-var isRequired = 'agent' == user.account_type.toLowerCase();
input(type='text', name="name", placeholder="Name", required=isRequired)
```